# Calculating angle when sine is known

Tags: c#, trigonometry, degrees

How can I calculate the angle in degrees when `Math.Sin` is known? Asine will work? and multiply it by 180 and divide by pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but remember that 135 degrees has the same value for Sin(ang) as 45 degrees does. So your answer is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.

For more information, read this : http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/angles/angles.htm